# how to use a vector and its `rev` to create 2 zips?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a module to check matching brackets.

Here is my code :

```rust
fn opposite(the_char: &char) -> char {
    let a: &str = &the_char.to_string()[..];
    match a {
        "{" => String::from("}").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        "}" => String::from("{").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        "(" => String::from(")").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        ")" => String::from("(").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        "[" => String::from("]").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        "]" => String::from("[").chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[0],
        _ => panic!("That character is not part of the search")
    }
}

fn create_const() -> [Vec<char>; 2] {
    let opening: Vec<char> = "{[(".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let closing: Vec<char> = "}])".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    [ opening, closing]
}

fn test() -> bool {

    let [opening, closing] = create_const();
    let modif_string = "[{}{}(){]";
    
    let open_chars = modif_string.chars().filter(|x| opening.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let close_chars = modif_string.chars().filter(|x| closing.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<char>>();
    
    if open_chars.len() != close_chars.len() {
        return false;
    }
    
    let open_chars_opp = open_chars.iter().map(|x| opposite(&x));
    let it = open_chars_opp.zip(close_chars);
    let it_rev = open_chars_opp.rev().zip(close_chars);

    it.into_iter().all(|(x, y)| x == y) || it_rev.into_iter().all(|(x, y)| x == y)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}",test())
}
```

I am getting an ownership issue in this section :

```rust
let open_chars_opp = open_chars.iter().map(|x| opposite(&x));
let it = open_chars_opp.zip(close_chars);
let it_rev = open_chars_opp.rev().zip(close_chars);
```

because of my use of `zip` twice on the same vector I think. How can I solve that issue ?

[LINK TO THE PLAYGROUND](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=694d60ea414a7b2de5f6ce19add2eaf4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not using `zip()` twice, but using `open_chars_opp` twice, once by calling [`zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip), once by calling [`rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev). As you can see in the method signature, both take `self` by value, not by reference, so after the first invocation, the value is moved and can't be used again.

`open_chars_opp` implements the [Clone trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), so you can just call [`clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) on `open_chars_opp` before the first usage. There is a similar problem for `close_chars`, after fixing both, your code compiles and looks like this:

```rust
let open_chars_opp = open_chars.iter().map(|x| opposite(&x));
let it = open_chars_opp.clone().zip(close_chars.clone());
let it_rev = open_chars_opp.rev().zip(close_chars);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f6c2712f70b143853e5e8e158d8321d)